# JAGS errors: "Resolving undeclared variables" and "Invalid vector argument to exp"

Tags: r, jags, winbugs, r2jags

This is my first time using JAGS and I ran into some errors when modeling my data.

Here is a brief description of my data:
A total of `n` people (e.g., 2) each solved `m` problems (e.g., 6). All problems have 3 answers, each of a certain value `V`.

Here is [the graphic model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHO7W.png) (some variable names are different: `IG` and `y` are the same as `V` and `answer`, respectively; `x` is not included in my model).

The probability that Person `i` chooses each answer for Problem `j` follows the "softmax decision rule": `exp(V[j,]/tau[i])/sum(exp(V[j,]/tau[i]))`. Here, tau is the noise in decision with a Gamma distribution: tao → 0, a person chooses the answer of the highest value; tao → ∞, a person chooses randomly among 3 answers.

This is my model file `model.txt`:

```
model{
    # data
    for(i in 1:n) # for each person
    {
        for (j in 1:m) # for each problem
        {
            # answer chosen
            answer[i,j] ~ dcat(exp(V[j,]/tau[i])/sum(exp(V[j,]/tau[i])))
        }
    }
    # priors
    for (i in 1:n)
    {
        tau[i] ~ dgamma(0.001,0.001)
    }
}
```

Here's my R script:

```
library(R2jags)
m <- 6 # number of problems
n <- 2 # number of people
V <- matrix(c(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)), nrow=m, ncol=3, byrow = T)
answer <- matrix(c(2,3,1,1,2,3,1,1,1,1,3,2), nrow=n, ncol=m, byrow = T) 

data <- list("m", "n", "V", "answer")
myinits <- list(list(tau = rep(1,n)))
parameters <- c("tau")

samples <- jags(data, inits=myinits, parameters,
                model.file ="model.txt", n.chains=1, n.iter=1000, 
                n.burnin=1, n.thin=1, DIC=T)
```

After running the script in R, I got the error message below:

> Compiling model graph 
>     Resolving undeclared variables 
>     Allocating nodes
>   Deleting model
>
> Error in jags.model(model.file, data = data, inits = init.values,
>   n.chains = n.chains,  :    RUNTIME ERROR: Invalid vector argument to
>   exp

What might be the problem? Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You are supplying a column vector from `V` to `exp`. In JAGS, inverse link functions can only be given scalar values. Basically, to properly code out softmax regression you will need to iterate through each element of `V`. Additionally, `V` must be a three dimensional vector (person x subject x 3 choices).

```
model{
    # data
    for(i in 1:n) # for each person
    {
        for (j in 1:m) # for each problem
        {
            # answer chosen
            answer[i,j] ~ dcat(mu[i,j,1:3])
            mu[i,j,1:3] <- exp_v[i,j,1:3] / sum(exp_v[i,j,1:3])
              for (k in 1:3) {
                exp_v[i,j,k] <- exp(V[i,j,k]/tau[i])
        }
    }
    # priors
    for (i in 1:n)
    {
        tau[i] ~ dgamma(0.001,0.001)
    }
}
```

Unlike your model, `V` is indexed to `i,j,k` instead of what I would assume to be `j` and `k`. You would need to restructure your `V` array in order to fit this. However, fitting the model this way allows you to input a scalar to `exp`, which you can then sum afterwards.

Comment: It worked! Thank you for your answer! (I didn't know JAGS can't exponentiate vectors before!)